# Android get Notification in android 4.3

Tags: android, reflection, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

In Android 4.3 the class NotificationListenerService was added. In this method:

```
onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn)
```

You can get the Notification but not its extras, so you are missing its content or title for example. In Android KitKat you just need to refer to the extras,  but is their a way to get every notifications extras in android 4.3. I tried it with reflection and its working in some cases but its not the best solution. With most apps you get a null pointer. How the other apps get that information?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I tired sometimes ago but you have to use really a vodoo code to get the information and it's really unreliable, I suggest you to do coding for this feature only for KitKat